# Cordova-plugin-fcm: Cannot find name 'FCMPlugin'

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use FCM push notifications with my Ionic 2 app via cordova-fcm-plugin.

I've followed every tutorial and it's working fine when i send a push from the firebase console, but i want to do some stuff in my app using its functionalities and the payload, but when i try to use any method from the plugin i get a **Cannot find name 'FCMPlugin'** error on Visual Studio:
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2GRu.png)
I've been looking for how to use it correctly and haven't found anything, just this question: [The Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599340/cordova-plugin-fcm-fcmplugin-is-not-defined)

So what is the correctly way to implement and use the plugin? Is there a module? I can call it from the 'ionic-native'? I have to import it from somewhere? Just use the plugin .js file link in the index.html? Or this error is commom and in emulation/building it'll work fine?

Thanks :D

**PS:** I've not tryed to build it or emulate it to see what happens, going to do this now.

### EDIT

Ok, so it's an error that won't let me build my app. Rly need to know how to use the plugin now.

Comment: Found a solution, if anyone has one that is better please post. I **declare** a **var** with **FCMPlugin: any** name within my imports, this is working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to declare the FCMPlugin variable after your imports:

```
import { Foo}  from  '../pages/foo/foo';
import { Bar } from  '../pages/bar/bar';
declare var FCMPlugin: any; // <---- this is the magic line
```

Comment: I wish it would have been specified in the original doc.