# How to use cordova-plugin-firebase-realtime-database in ionic2?

Tags: cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, cordova-plugins

I want to use **cordova-plugin-firebase-realtime-database** because it provides the native sdk and **setDatabasePersistent** to write data to the disk

I want to know how to use it in ionic 2.

How do I import this plugin with typescript? How do I retrieve data array and objects with it in typescript?

The docs say that I should manually add this to phonegap build:

```
buildscript {
...
dependencies {
...
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
}
```

Should I add it in ionic 2 too?

Finally, after install, the plugin says that **FirebaseDatabasePlugin is not defined** how to avoid that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cordova-plugin-fcm - FCMPlugin is not defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599340/cordova-plugin-fcm-fcmplugin-is-not-defined)

Comment: This Plugin is different from the plugin you are posted in your comment ?